# How do I remove wine and playonlinux completely?

Tags: 13.10, wine, uninstall, playonlinux

*PlayOnLinux* isn't working, so I uninstalled and then re-installed it. But still it isn't working. I think I did not uninstall it correctly. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

After uninstalling PlayOnLinux, delete the hidden folder `.PlayOnLinux` in your home directory and it's link:

```
rm -r ~/.PlayOnLinux ~/"PlayOnLinux's virtual drives"
```

Now reinstall PlayOnLinux.

Comment: rm: cannot remove ‘/home/hybrid/.PlayOnLinux’: Is a directory

Comment: @virtualxtc fixed it

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all the `sudo apt-get remove wine` and `"rm ~/.blahblahblah here"` and wine will still be there. I installed synaptic package manager and removed from there. This got it all out. Copy and paste this into your teminal:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

run the manager, type in the search window ***wine*** right click on the ones with a green box that has wine in it's description, and choose  ***mark for complete removal*** then go to the top tool bar, find the green check with apply written underneath and click it. Wine is now gone. Hope this helps those who are stuck with other methods and no results.
Good Luck!

Ubuntu 13.10 64bit
Memeory:   4-8GiB DDR3 PC3-15000 1866MHz 
Processor: AMD FX(tm)-8150 Eight-Core Processor x8
Graphics:  AMD Radeon HD 7800 Series
MOBO:      SABERTOOTH 990FX R2.0

Answer (score 1):

this should do the job

```
sudo apt-get remove wine playonlinux
```

and if you dont want the configuration files you should change the `remove` for `purge`

and then remove the folder like @the_Seppi says.